# String getting truncated in OSS ASN1 decoding

Tags: asn.1

Some byte strings are getting truncated while printing using OSS ASN.1 decoder. Java Compiler.

'11001111 11111001 11000111 11111000 101'B --truncated--

For LTE-RRC. Other fields are parsing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact their support if you have questions about their product.  Note, however, that X.680 says that for a BIT STRING with named bits, encodings are free to add/remove trailing zero bits and therefore such values should be treated as semantically equivalent.  I don't know whether that applies to your case or not, but if so, it would explain what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with OSS's Java tools, but there's something called a [`Asn1ValueFormat` class](https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/documentation/asn1_java_8.3/api/toed/com/oss/util/ASN1ValueFormat.html) in their TOED library, which has a `setTruncationLimit` method, and there's something similar in their SOED library too. This can be used with [`toString()` method](https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/documentation/asn1_java_8.3/api/soed/com/oss/asn1/AbstractData.html#toString-com.oss.util.ASN1ValueFormat-).

I don't have access to the tools I'm afraid, but that might be worth a look.